# How to fetch a custom attribute from Kinvey

Tags: ios, swift, kinvey

I am looking to fetch a custom attribute I added to a user called "PostCount". I am looking to fetch it and set it to a label to view the post count. I successfully can increment the active user's PostCount but am unsuccessful at fetching it to display it.

Here is what I think I should be using.

```
var query = KCSQuery(onField: "PostCount", usingConditional: KCSQueryConditional.KCSAll, forValue: 4)
store.queryWithQuery(query, withCompletionBlock: "Not sure what to do here",withProgressBlock: "or here")
```

I think I need to use this, but I am not sure what the completionBlock or progressBlock would be.

Answer (score 0):

Because it was a custom attribute under the user, it did not use the KCSQuery(). Instead I did the following

```
KCSUser.activeUser().getValueForAttribute("PostCount")
```

This retrieved the number stored in my post count, which I then set to the label I was displaying.